# How to wipe my hard drive on busybox? Messed up trying to install galliumOS with unetBootIn,

Tags: linux, chromebook, busybox

So, I am using my school computer to make my flash drive bootable so I can install galliumOS on my personal computer which is a chromebook. I used unetBootIn to make my flash drive live and it ended up completely messing up my computer. I can't install another OS because all it does it give me a BusyBox command prompt. The only way I have tried to fix this is by wiping my hard drive, however. I can't use `fdisk` or anything like that. I have tried using `rm -rf /*` but the folders are read-only and I don't have permission. I have tried researching this for hours and I'm at the point I want to smash this computer. I keep getting the error `can not mount /dev/loop2`. I'm genuinely lost and hopefully somebody can give me the answers. I just want to install a linux distro.

Comment: Try a different USB key and use Rufus to make it bootable. Rufus should work fine and not cause this issue.

Comment: can't use rufus, only have chromeos